# Not Drawing QWT Plot Axis

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I'm trying to draw a plot using QWT without any title or axis labels.  Not drawing the title seems easy, all you have to do is not pass it in a title, or if there already is one, just give it an empty string (like this):

```
ui->plot->setAxisTitle(QwtPlot::xBottom, "");
ui->plot->setAxisTitle(QwtPlot::yLeft, "");
```

But the actual labels (inside the axisScale property) are drawn by default (going from 0 to 1000 in both x and y). However even though I can change the way it looks, I can't remove it altogether.

So is there any way to draw a qwt plot without any axis labels or titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the scale or the labels, this will work:

```
ui->plot->enableAxis(QwtPlot::xBottom, false);
ui->plot->enableAxis(QwtPlot::yLeft, false);
```

If you want to show the scales with no labels, you can implement your own `QwtScaleDraw` object that returns an empty `QwtText` object for all of the labels:

```
class MyScaleDraw : public QwtScaleDraw
{
public:
    MyScaleDraw() : QwtScaleDraw() { }
    virtual ~MyScaleDraw() { }
    virtual QwtText label(double) const
    {
        return QwtText();
    }
};

//...

ui->plot->setAxisScaleDraw(Qwt::xBottom, new MyScaleDraw);
ui->plot->setAxisScaleDraw(Qwt::yLeft, new MyScaleDraw);
```

There may be a better way, but this is one I could think of.

Comment: I get: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QwtScaleDraw'

Comment: Try adding `#include "qwt_scale_draw.h"` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:
ui->plot->enableAxis(QwtPlot::yLeft, false);

But what happened is that my axis disappeared, but my plot is also squished into a thin horizontal bar.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Just found a nice way to do this:

```
ui->plot->axisScaleDraw(QwtPlot::xBottom)->enableComponent(QwtAbstractScaleDraw::ScaleComponent::Labels, false);
```

Also works with the ScaleComponents Ticks and Backbone.