# How to add the unit to the scale of the plot in qwtplot

Tags: qt, qwt

I want to create something like the image below:

I've looked in the qwtplot documentation, but I think it is not possible to be done.

Anyone ever tried it?
[image: Plots]

Comment: What is wrong with the link? I can't zoom in?

Comment: @Corijn I've corrected it.

Comment: So you just want the labels? 2.9s instead of 2.9?

Comment: @Corijn yes, and make the tittle come in the area of the plot, instead of its default place which is at the top.

Comment: does the solution work for you?

Comment: No, it did not help me. I don't want to hide the labels. i wnat to add a suffix to the scale values.

Comment: You should adapt the code in the redefinition of the function. I extended my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this question's answer: [Not Drawing QWT Plot Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872787/not-drawing-qwt-plot-axis)
You should create your own `QwtScaleDraw` subclass and redefine `virtual QwtText label(double) const` as described in the link to something like this:

```
    virtual QwtText label(double val) const
    {
         return QwtText(QString::number(val) + "s");
    }
```

For more information on format and precision of the value have a look [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number-2).

You can add a custom label using [QwtPlotMarker](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_marker.html).
This may look like this:

```
    QwtPlotMarker marker = new QwtPlotMarker();
    marker->attach(your_plot_instance);
    marker->setValue(0.0, 0.0); // location of the label in plot coordinates
    marker->setLabel("title");
```

If you want to set more properties for the plot marker, please have a look at the [QwtPlotMarker doc](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_marker.html)

Comment: thanks, it worked, but i can't figure out know how to change the title.

Comment: QwtText title("some_text");
plot->setTitle(title);

Comment: I know that, the problem is not editing it. is putting it inside the plot's zone.

Comment: My suggestion: don't show a normal title and use a QwtPlotMarker as I wrote. I will update my answer with a short code example.

Comment: QwtPlotMarker has more flexibility than just a QLabel. For instance setting the position is possible in plot coordinates, which is very convenient.